# Как лучше хранить бинарные данные в БД MySQL

Tags: mysql

Как лучше хранить бинарные данные в БД MySQL при условии что они(данные) периодически будут выводиться на экран браузера админа?

- bigint
- blob
- другое ?

P.S. это нужно для логирования команд отправляемых на свитчи и получаемых ответов.

**UPDATE**
В данном случае проблема именно в том, что админ закалённый Сишник, и для отладки свитчей ему надо видеть какие биты были отправлены и получены.

Comment: Какой размер этих данных?

Comment: Произвольный. Это может быть сама команда(несколько байт) до целого архива + CRC.

Comment: @shurik вам правильно ответил. Различие между blob и text в том, в text не учитывается регистр символов при операциях с данным полем. А как вы их отображать собираетесь?

Comment: @istem это будет отдельное извращение на php. Вариантов куча, но скорее всего попробую конвертировать в строку и напечатать.

Comment: Мусье знает толк в извращениях.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Бинарные данные как правило не читаемые, это могут быть какие то картинки (просто для примера) или какая то структура в бинарном формате.

Если вы не собираетесь добавлять индексы в это поле - то всё равно как его хранить.

bigint - вообще не в тему к логированию.

Выбирайте между blob и text

Answer (score 2):

Соглашусь с [@shurik](/users/1182/shurik) хранить логи, если уж они настолько большие то в поле text, а вот если это архив, тогда архив гагружать на сервак в какую-то папку, а в БД писать название архива и\или путь к нему для скачки. Хранить архив в бд не айс.